# Alternative for macros or procedures in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have Teradata SQL query that will provide values for each day, I need to run this query for months. My organization doesn't allow me to use macros or procedures, is there any alternatives apart from these two things that will automate my SQL query in Teradata. Apologies I cannot display sample code in here

Comment: Did you try creating the macro in your user? *values for each day, I need to run this query for months*  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: so, for example, the query gives me the number of visits on April 1st, in order to get the total visits of April, I have to manually run the query for 30 days. I can't select a longer time frame in the query because of the logic. So is there any looping kind of mechanisms/functions I can use?

Comment: I doubt that you *can't select a longer time frame in the query because of the logic* But you could insert the 30 days into a Volatile Table and run your Select for each date using a recursive query

Comment: You can run scripts from the command line using sqla or bteq.  The command you use to invoke it from the command line can be added to a scheduler.

Comment: @DavidCram can you give me little more information about this bteq/sqla

Comment: sqla is just the executable that launches SQL Assistant.  When invoked from the command line you can pass startup parameters that will automatically connect and run your script.  So this will just make SQL Assistant pop up and start running.  So it is probably only a good idea if you want to actually watch it pop up and run.   Documentation on sqla startup parameters is here: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/HH8~IyFfLq4okp1pES~6cA/Y2R9V5NNkVBy1FNb343VwQ

Comment: BTEQ is a teradata tool that can be invoked from the command line and is probably the better choice for unattended execution.  Documentation can be found here: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/jmAxXLdiDu6NiyjT6hhk7g/~Hy5lbZSS5zSwwnQv7yRWg